# PHP HTTP POST Question - How do you pass data from multiple forms as HTTP Post?

Tags: php

I have a step 1 page, and a step 2 page. I want to take the information from step 1 page, then step 2 page, and save as session information (which i have already done). Once this information is all gathered i then want to be able to submit it to another php page using HTTP POST.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to send the data using `POST` you'll need to bring those variables down as hidden input fields on your form before your users clicks submit:

```
<input type="hidden" name="firstname" value="<?php echo($_SESSION['firstname']); ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="surname" value="<?php echo($_SESSION['surname']); ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="age" value="<?php echo($_SESSION['age']); ?>" />
```

Alternatively you could just reference the `$_SESSION` when your at the processing stage, if this is applicable.

Comment: *what if its information that can't be seen like a userid number or something like that? i just thought about that issue

Comment: If the item exists within the session you will be able to render it in your HTML, alternatively you can access the session directly on your processing page.

Answer (score 3):

As ILMV said, on subsequent pages you can copy the previous page's details into hidden fields.

Alternatively, if splitting your form into pages is a design decision rather than a technical one, you could output the whole form in one go and then use javascript to show only a certain number of elements at a time.

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="requested_amount" value="<? echo $_SESSION['requested_amount'] ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="first_name" value="<? echo $_SESSION['first_name'] ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="last_name" value="<? echo $_SESSION['last_name'] ?>" />


had to use echo.... but yes good call i'll just use that for now.

Comment: This "certain number of elements" at a time trick is actually pretty good, it degrades nicely if JavaScript is disabled and solves the problem.

Comment: what if its information that can't be seen like a userid number or something like that? i just thought about that issue